# add class to each line of css with regex

Tags: regex

I want to add a class at the start of each line of my css

I want

```
.more {
    padding: 5px 10px 0;
}

#fbook {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    width: 320px;
}
```

to look like

```
.test .more {
    padding: 5px 10px 0;
}

.test #fbook {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    width: 320px;
}
```

something like this.

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$
```

would work if my css looked like this

```
more
{
    padding: 5px 10px 0;
}

fbook
{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 4px;
    width: 320px;
}
```

but I can't seem to get anything working when to find the . # {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?i)^([.#a-z]+\{)$/m', '.test $1', $subject);
```

**Explanation**

```
"
(?im)         # Match the remainder of the regex with the options: case insensitive (i); ^ and \$ match at line breaks (m)
^             # Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character)
(             # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [.#a-z]       # Match a single character present in the list below
                    # One of the characters “.#”
                    # A character in the range between “a” and “z”
      +             # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \{            # Match the character “{” literally
)
\$             # Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character)
"
```

Comment: thanks for your help I couldn't quite get this working but your detailed explanation has given me enough to go forward!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a modern tool like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). Simply take your code, and wrap it with `.test{` `}`:

```
.test {
    .more {
        padding: 5px 10px 0;
    }

    #fbook {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 0 4px;
        width: 320px;
    }
}
```

If you only need it one time, you can do it online: http://leafo.net/lessphp/#demo
If you want to do it from time to time, there are less libraries for many languages which you can use, and a client side JavaScript option.

Comment: I considered less but don't have much access in the system I am editing (only css access) so find and replace is the only way I can think of, but LESS will come in handy in the future I would say.